# When does Spring ApplicationContext register itself to BeanFactory?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to read source code of spring-boot, and I want to find out when Spring ApplicationContext register itself to BeanFactory. As we can get ApplicationContext by Autowire it as a field like:

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;
```

,so I think there must be some where the ApplicationContext register itself to BeanFactory in source code.If someone know where it locates, please show me. I will appreciate it.

Comment: Never... The `ApplicationContext` itself is a `BeanFactory`... and the auto wiring of the `ApplicationContext` is basically assigning the current context to that field.

Comment: Thank you! You may right.I will read the code of auto wiring first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [AbstractApplicationContext line 653](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.java#L653):

```
beanFactory.registerResolvableDependency(ApplicationContext.class, this);
```